# Python Data Export/Import to/from Excel Files

Tags: python, excel, python-3.5

I have written the Following code in Python 3.5.
The Problem is that I want the value taken from user to be stored in excel and when the program restarts, it automatically reads all the data from the saved excel file. I am sure there is some way I can do that. Please guide me. I am almost a beginner at Python.

Also Please Check code for errors. It sometimes runs perfectly while sometimes when it asks to repeat and I say no, it still repeats.

```
name=[]
roll=[]
grade=[]
omarks=[]
tmarks=[]
p=-1

while True:
    st=input("Do You want to add a Data or Search the Existing Data? \n1=Search \n2=Add \n3=Print All Data???\n")

    while st=="3" or st=="P" or st=="Print" or st=="print" or st=="p":
        for i in range (len(name)):
            print ("Name of the Student: ",(name[i]))
            print ("Roll Number:",(roll[i]))
            print ("Class of the Student:",(grade[i]))
            print (" ")
        rpp=input("Repeat?? Y?N: ")
        if rpp=="Y" or rpp=="y" or rpp== "Yes" or rpp=="YES" or rpp=="yes" or rpp=="1":
            continue
        if rpp=="N" or rpp=="n" or rpp== "No" or rpp=="NO" or rpp=="no" or rpp=="0":
            break

    while st=="2" or st=="A" or st=="Add" or st=="add" or st=="a":
        nm=str(input("Enter The Name Here: "))
        rl=int(input("Enter The Roll Number Here: "))
        gr=int(input("Enter The Class Number Here: "))
        om=int(input("Enter the Obtained Marks Here: "))
        tm=int(input("Enter the Total Marks Here: "))
        name.append(nm)
        roll.append(rl)
        grade.append(gr)
        omarks.append(om)
        tmarks.append(tm)
        rpa=input("Add Another?? Y?N: ")
        if rpa=="Y" or rpa=="y" or rpa== "Yes" or rpa=="YES" or rpa=="yes" or rpa=="1":
            continue
        if rpa=="N" or rpa=="n" or rpa== "No" or rpa=="NO" or rpa=="no" or rpa=="0":
            break
    while st=="1" or st=="S" or st=="Search" or st=="s" or st== "search":
        rn=int(input("Enter the Roll Number Here: "))
        for i in range (len(roll)):
            if rn==roll[i]:
                #p=i
                print ("Name of the Student: ",name[i])
                print ("Class of the Student: ",grade[i])
                print ("Obtained Marks: ",omarks[i])
                print ("Total Marks: ",tmarks[i])
            else:
                print ("The Roll Number Could not be Found! Search Again or Add the Data.")
            rps=input("Search Again?? Y?N: ")
            if rps=="Y" or rps=="y" or rps== "Yes" or rps=="YES" or rps=="yes" or rps=="1":
                continue
            elif rps=="N" or rps=="n" or rps== "No" or rps=="NO" or rps=="no" or rps=="0":
                break

    rp=input("Repeat The Program?? Y?N: ")
    if rp=="Y" or rp=="y" or rp== "Yes" or rp=="YES" or rp=="yes" or rp==1:
        continue
    if rp=="N" or rp=="n" or rp== "No" or rp=="NO" or rp=="no" or rp==0:
        break

try:
    untrusted.execute()
except: # catch *all* exceptions
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    write_to_page( "<p>Error: %s</p>" % e )
```

Comment: Its better if you start learning how to debug code. from your problem specification it seems, you have problem in breaking the loop, so double check the conditions which are not working as per your expectation.

Comment: one thing before comparing rp with 1 or 0, convert rp to integer as `int(rp)`, otherwise it won't work for input 1 or 0.

Comment: Actually naming your variables meaningful names might help too...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a copy problem but the indenting seems wrong for the final if statements. Outside of that it would be easier to debug your logic problem if your code was easier to read - there are many shortcuts in python that you can use here, for example instead of

```
if rpa=="Y" or rpa=="y" or rpa== "Yes" or rpa=="YES" or rpa=="yes" or rpa=="1":
```

you can use

```
if rpa.lower() in ['y', 'yes', '1']:
```

Also, you don't need a continue statement at the end of a while - it will continue automatically if not broken.

I would also make sure of which "repeat" section isn't working - you have several that look that same, maybe put a number in the repeat question.

I don't know what logic issue you're having but hopefully the above helps you find it.

Answer (score -1):

I am giving an example of reading and writing from/to excel files in python. Note that there are many alternative packages you can use in python to read and write to excel files. Look at [here](http://www.python-excel.org/) for all the available packages. I am giving an example using [xlrd](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [xlwt](http://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  which i generally use while reading from and writing to excel files.

**Reading from Excel file**:

```
import xlrd

fname = 'Cad Data Mar 2014.xlsx'

# Open the workbook
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)

# List sheet names, and pull a sheet by name
sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
print('Sheet Names', sheet_names)

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

# Or grab the first sheet by index 
#  (sheets are zero-indexed)
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print ('Sheet name: %s' % xl_sheet.name)

# Pull the first row by index
#  (rows/columns are also zero-indexed)
row = xl_sheet.row(0)  # 1st row

# Print 1st row values and types
from xlrd.sheet import ctype_text   

print('(Column #) type:value')
for idx, cell_obj in enumerate(row):
    cell_type_str = ctype_text.get(cell_obj.ctype, 'unknown type')
    print('(%s) %s %s' % (idx, cell_type_str, cell_obj.value))

# Print all values, iterating through rows and columns
num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols   # Number of columns
for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):    # Iterate through rows
    print ('-'*40)
    print ('Row: %s' % row_idx)   # Print row number
    for col_idx in range(0, num_cols):  # Iterate through columns
        cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)  # Get cell object by row, col
        print ('Column: [%s] cell_obj: [%s]' % (col_idx, cell_obj))
```

**Writing to Excel file**:

```
import xlwt

# Data that we want to write to an Excel file
DATA = (("The Essential Calvin and Hobbes", 1988,),
        ("The Authoritative Calvin and Hobbes", 1990,),
        ("The Indispensable Calvin and Hobbes", 1992,),
        ("Attack of the Deranged Mutant Killer Monster Snow Goons", 1992,),
        ("The Days Are Just Packed", 1993,),
        ("Homicidal Psycho Jungle Cat", 1994,),
        ("There's Treasure Everywhere", 1996,),
        ("It's a Magical World", 1996,),)

# Open the workbook
wb = xlwt.Workbook()

# Add a sheet to the workbook
ws = wb.add_sheet("My Sheet")

# Print all values, iterating through rows and columns
for i, row in enumerate(DATA):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(i, j, col)

# Set the width for 1st column in the workbook
# You can skip this line and see what happens!
ws.col(0).width = 256 * max([len(row[0]) for row in DATA])

# Save the workbook
wb.save("myworkbook.xls")
```

There are plenty of other examples on web which you can see if you need more brief examples.

Comment: Wasi bhai, this is not the solution.

Comment: I know this is not a solution but OP can solve his problem from this example. I believe: giving an example to learn and then modify the example to serve the need. In this way, OP will be able to learn and solve the problem at the same time. In SO, we help programmers to resolve their problems but SO is not a solution provider!!